# How to detect mode, then execute?

Tags: major-mode

I'm currently using [autoheader](http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/349779/pro_tip_get_automatic_headers_when_create_new/).

I have this configuration, which causes the `<?php` tag to be inserted in other modes:

```el
(defsubst my/header-title ()
  "Insert buffer's first row."

  (insert "<?php \n \n" (concat comment-start  " Foo bar "  (and (= 1 (length comment-start)) header-prefix-string )
                                (if (buffer-file-name)
                                    (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))
                                  (buffer-name))
                                " " "\n"))
  )  

(setq make-header-hook '( my/header-title))  

;; To have Emacs add a file header whenever you create a new file in some mode: 
(autoload 'auto-make-header "header2")
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'auto-make-header) 
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'auto-make-header)
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'auto-make-header)
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'auto-make-header)
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'auto-make-header)
```

When I'm creating a new file with the extension `.html` or `.lisp`, then the `<?php` opening tag will be inserted too. I want the `<?php` opening tag inserted in the header only when the newly created buffer is in PHP-mode.  When PHP-mode is not enabled, it should not insert the PHP tag.

I tried to solve this with the following modifications:

```el
(defsubst my/header-title ()
   (insert 
   ;; comparison major mode with the PHP-mode
    (if equal major-mode "PHP-mode" 
    ;; If true, insert this:
      ("<?php \n \n") 
    ;; If false, insert empty string
  " \n")
   (concat[...] rest of the function)))
```

But it doesn't work. The comparison seems logical, following the Emacs manual. So I couldn't figure it out. So I'm wondering how I could detect if there is PHP-mode enabled, then insert the `<?php` tag, or otherwise do nothing?

Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, Check your last snippet more carefully, it's full of unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the mention, I added two parentheses. Still missing an intelligent parentheses balancer, that adds the parentheses for you. Smartparens and Paredit didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this part

```
equal major-mode "PHP-mode"
```

With this expression

```
(equal major-mode 'php-mode)
```

Comment: I would love to try your comment out. I configured it on your way: http://pastebin.com/V8vDjGEE but I got an error that the function `php-tag` or `empty-tag` is void. Any suggestion?

Comment: @ReneFrogertjuh yes, replace `(php-tag)` with `php-tag`. And replace `(" \n")` with `" \n"`.

Comment: It worked now. I always thought you need to pack everything in parenthesese, except strings. Didn't see clearly that php-tag was a variable. Thanks Malabarba, I marked your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `auto-make-header` contains php related header, this hook must be added only to php as, `(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'auto-make-header)`. You can remove all the other `add-hook` statements.

Comment: I don't get it? I have a custom header. So only the custom header must be activated, not the default auto-header. And the same custom header will be applied on many different modes.

Comment: you say, your custom header that adds --- `<?php \n \n` must be added for many different modes

Comment: I couldn't figure your answer out. I will read the documentation again, in order if your answer is the helpful one.